# listings with R: keywords in variable names are highlighted when using underscores?

Tags: listings, r

When using `language=R` as a `lstlisting`s `style`, if a variable name contains a keyword surrounded by underscores it will be highlighted. See the image and code example below. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Other languages like Java seem to work fine, as do variable names without underscores. I tried `alsoletter=_` but that doesn't change anything.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\lstdefinestyle{generalStyle} {
    frame=single,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{magenta}
}

\lstdefinestyle{JavaStyle} {
    language=Java, 
    style=generalStyle
}

\lstdefinestyle{RStyle} {
    language=R,
    style=generalStyle  
}

\begin{document}

    Java
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=JavaStyle]
        some_String_int_thing = "Somestring"
    \end{lstlisting}

    R
    \begin{lstlisting}[style=RStyle]
        some_data_csv_thing = 'Somestring'
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R syntax highlighting is defined in `lstlang3.sty`.  The definition for R in that file contains the following:

```
 otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},
 alsoother={._$},
```

If you want to remove the special treatment of `_` then add something like this to your own definition of `RStyle`

```
 otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,/},
 alsoother={.$},
```

(that is, remove the underscores).  Besure to get the commas right at the end of the lines.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tried `otherkeywords` but missed the `alsoother` part.

Comment: Followup question: Is it possible to suppress highlighting of variable names that are single keywords, like `data` or `csv`? e.g. `data = 'something'` will highlight the `data`variable.

Comment: Hmm, follow up questions usually need a new question here.  But look at the definitions for R in your own version of `lstlang3.sty` - you can copy any or all of it into your own definition and change whatever you like.  In my personal opinion you should avoid using keywords as variable names, but R lets you do whatever you like, so feel free to edit your own language definition appropriately.

Comment: Sorry for breaking the rules! `deletekeywords={data}` seems to do the trick, although actual keywords like `data.frame` are consequently not highlighted. I totaly agree with you, one should avoid using keywords as variable names. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!